# Using Maps Geocode API from Azure website without Business account?

Tags: api, google-maps, azure, google-maps-api-3, azure-web-app-service

When you have a business account for the Google Maps Geocode API, you have to specify an extra parameter, "client", in every call:

```
  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=...&sensor=false&client=....
```

This way, the API can identify the caller and use the corresponding quota limitations.

When you don't have a business account, the call is simply like this:
(ie. no "client" parameter)

```
  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=...&sensor=false
```

So, the only way the API identifies the caller is by the IP Address.

I want to use the Geocode API in a free Azure Website and I don't have a business API account. This means that I will be calling the API from a shared IP that all other free websites in Azure are using. Apparently, the number of requests done by Azure Websites is always exceeded, because I'm getting:

```
  <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status>
```

(In the first try)

Question: Is there a way to tell the API "who I am" so that I get my free quota (the same quota that I'm getting when I call the URL from my personal computer with my personal IP)?

If not, do you know any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key)

Or use the [client side geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Comment: The "#api_key" in your first URL didnt lead me to any specifical part of the documentation (which I read). In this case I need the server side geocoder :(

Comment: There was a section titled API key (at least in the english version I was looking at).

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed looking the documentation in Spanish (not that I set that, it just detected my location). In the spanish version there was no #api_key section at all!  Will mark your answer as the accepted

Comment: I have heard that the versions of the site in other languages trail the English language version. The API_KEY in the request is a new thing, it used to cause issues if it was there (before it was added to the API).